# Raku: what is the syntax for shell calls with spaces?

Tags: windows, escaping, raku, quoting, command-line-arguments

Edit: I reported this as a bug to Raku:
qqx, shell not operating quotes properly
https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/3518

and one of the administrators referred me to
How should Proc::Async.new, run and shell call cmd.exe?
https://github.com/Raku/problem-solving/issues/20

which does sound exactly like what is occurring, especially the "It's not possible to escape spaces using ^." part.

If anyone comes up with a workaround, I would appreciate it.

Windows 7, and Windows 10-1909

Rakudo Star version 2019.03.1

How do I code this command in Raku?

```
fsutil usn readdata "C:/NtUtil/test 1"
```

The big bug-a-boo is that the file name has a space in it and Windows required double quotes around it.  Single quotes crash.

I can not get either of these two to work with a file name with a space in it.  fsutil either sees two parameters or one parameter where the name actually contains double quotes:

```
my @Result = qqx { C:/Windows/System32/fsutil.exe usn readdata "$FileName" }.lines;
for @Result -> $Line  { say $Line; };

my $proc=run( "dir", "$FileName", :out );
my @RtnStr  = $proc.out.slurp-rest.lines; 
for @RtnStr -> $Line { say $Line; }
```

Many thanks,
-T

Edit: added Windows 10-1909 to the fray

Edit:  no symptom change with "shell" command:

```
@Result = shell( "C:/Windows/System32/fsutil.exe usn readdata \"$FileName\"" ).lines;
for @Result -> $Line  { say $Line; };

Usage : fsutil usn readData <filename>
   Eg : fsutil usn readData C:\Temp\sample.txt

@Result = shell( "C:/Windows/System32/fsutil.exe usn readdata \"$FileName\"" );
for @Result -> $Line  { say $Line; };
```

Exit with:

```
Proc.new(in => IO::Pipe, out => IO::Pipe, err => IO::Pipe, exitcode => 1, signal => 0, pid => 1728, command => ("C:/Windows/System32/fsutil.exe usn readdata \"C:/NtUtil/test 1\"",))
```

Note the "exitcode => 1" and the last parameter with the back slashes in it

Edit: using the single quote method:

```
@Result = shell( 'C:/Windows/System32/fsutil.exe usn readdata "$FileName"' );
```

results in the same error:

```
Usage : fsutil usn readData <filename>
   Eg : fsutil usn readData C:\Temp\sample.txt
Error:  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Proc.new(in => IO::Pipe, out => IO::Pipe, err => IO::Pipe, exitcode => 1, signal => 0, pid => 1192, command => ("C:/Windows/System32/fsutil.exe usn readdata \"\$FileName\"",))
```

Comment: Why would you want to complicate things with using a Shell (cmd on Windows has crazy quoting rules). Just using `run` should work, no? `my $proc = run 'fsutil', 'usn', 'readdata', $FileName, :out;`

Comment: The only tag you put on your question was `[raku]`. Tags on SO impact what audience gets exposed to your question. By using just `[raku]` your question ended up being brought to the attention of all who look at questions tagged `[raku]` (with or without additional search criteria like "syntax" or "shell"). You obviously didn't mean to post spam, but that was one of the unfortunate outcomes of your question. I've fixed it for you now, but in future, please explore available tags by starting to write ones you imagine might exist, checking their descriptions, and adding the best few you can find.

Comment: Writing a [MRE] is partly about including sufficient information that your problem is reproducible. Readers can of course *guess* what you mean, but that is anathema on SO. As an example, you have shown neither the declaration, nor `say`'d output, of `$FileName`. (That's just an example.) Please test that an example you provide in a Q is reproducible before posting it. To do so, cut/paste your code, input, and output, and run it. (Specifying compiler version, platform details, etc. is also sometimes helpful.) In sum, it is anathema on SO to needlessly force readers to make presumptions.

Answer (score 4):

There's [`shell`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/shell):

```
shell('echo "two words"'); # OUTPUT: «two words»
```

That's going to be the same here and there. It will also use existing common shell for any operating system. You can also use variables, provided you escape quotes destined for the shell:

```
my $words = "two words"
shell("echo \"$words\"")
```

or

```
shell "echo \""~ $words ~ "\""
```

Comment: JJ.  Please address the problem I presented, which is not "echo".  You need to demonstrate how to actually call the command I ask about and actually test it.  All of your "echo" solutions have been tried and them some, including Q["] ~ .  Since you are the one that closed the bug on this, please demonstrate that it is not a bug.

Comment: So, does `shell('echo "two words"');` work for you or not?

Comment: Hi Elizabeth.  I don't care if echo works or not.  I want `fsutil usn readdata "C:/NtUtil/test 1"` to work.   I will place the results of using a single quote in the original post -T   No symptom change

Comment: Then don't expect an answer, if you don't want to give an answer to a simple question.  Because from Raku's point of view, there shouldn't be a difference in the handling of your specific request, and the "echo" example.  The "echo" question is about creating a minimal example that shows the problem.

Comment: I think Windows sees the extra quotes as part of the actual file name

Comment: @Todd that's Windows problem, not Raku. And anyway you would do better if you upgraded to a supported version of Windows, or to PowerShell over CMD. Also, please try to use "shell" instead of quotes.

Comment: There is no “supported version of Windows” for this problem, nor is this not Raku problem (and hence why libuv, nodejs, Java, etc handle this specific case in different ways). Nor can one say just use powershell because Raku literally uses cmd /c — https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/b6851c3e7e6ec022936c5dd9d40cc0cbaa4b1d35/src/core.c/Proc.pm6#L176 What exactly are all these claims based on?

Comment: @ugexe you are right in most of what you say, but the initial question mentioned Windows 7, which is out of support by Microsoft. Thus, "not supported". And you can use powershell by just running it, using shell or anything else (although my take is that it's got a similar problem, although you can overtake it by using PS data structures and getting them through to your program that way)

Comment: You are aware that you can launch cmd.exe from powershell right? Because “just use powershell” doesn’t mean squat if run/shell prefix your powershell command with cmd.exe /c

Answer (score 2):

Hello i've been testing Perl6 now Raku from windows 7 to windows 10.
i dont know if this solves the problem but for me it works :
in a file.rk or file.pl write :

shell "fsutil fsinfo drives & pause";

both fsutil and pause work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

> You can try escaping the space in the file path with `^`

Example:

```
c:\Documents^ and^ Settings\a.bat
```

Comment: see: How should Proc::Async.new, run and shell call cmd.exe?
https://github.com/Raku/problem-solving/issues/20

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround for anyone stopped because of this bug:
I am taking advantage of the Windows build in batch programming language:

```
my $PathIAm = $?FILE;
( my $IAm = $PathIAm ) ~~ s| .* "/" ||;

my Str $BatFile = $PathIAm ~ ".bat";
$BatFile ~~ s:global| '\\' |/|;

my Str $OS = $*KERNEL.name;
if not $OS eq "win32" { 
   say "Sorry, $IAm only work in Windows.";
   exit; }
( $IAm = $PathIAm ) ~~ s| .* '\\' ||;

my Str $CmdStr = 
   Q[@echo off] ~ "\n" ~
   Q[C:\Windows\System32\fsutil.exe usn readdata ] ~
   Q["] ~ $FileName ~ Q["] ~ "\n";
# say $CmdStr;


spurt( $BatFile, $CmdStr );
say qqx { $BatFile };
```

Result:

```
C:\NtUtil>raku k:\Windows\NtUtil\FileAttributes.pl6 "Test 1"

Major Version    : 0x3
Minor Version    : 0x0
FileRef#         : 0x00000000000000000058000000000340
Parent FileRef#  : 0x00000000000000000013000000000eb9
Usn              : 0x00000000711dab68
Time Stamp       : 0x0000000000000000 12:00:00 AM 1/1/1601
Reason           : 0x0
Source Info      : 0x0
Security Id      : 0x0
File Attributes  : 0x20
File Name Length : 0xc
File Name Offset : 0x4c
```

Answer (score 0):

I messed w this for quite a while; just about called it quits w Raku even.  Finally came up with this using powershell: Hope this helps somebody.

```
my $vscode = q/C:\Users\pb\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe/;
my $file = q/C:\temp\Notes 2023-09.md/;
qqx{echo \& \"$vscode\" \"$file\"};
```

Edit: to answer original question

```
my $fsutil = q/C:\Windows\System32\fsutil.exe/;
my $file = q/C:\temp\Notes 2023-09.md/;
say qqx{echo \& \"$fsutil\" usn readdata \"$file\"};
```